# Счёт упоминаний уникальных значений в датафрейме

Tags: python

Считаю кол-во упоминаний уникальных значений в столбце следующим образом:

## вывожу уникальные значения, функция юник

```
df["Столбец_1"].unique()
```

## считаю уникальные значения в столбце датафрейма

```
data= Counter(df["Столбец_1"])
```

Чтобы посчитать кол-во упоминаний всех уникальных значений во всех столбцах датафрейма, приходится вручную их перебирать. А есть ли способ так же быстро сделать данную операцию для всего датафрейма? Для всех столбцов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по тому что вы используете Counter, результат вам нужен в виде словаря. если это так, то можно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 
                   'col2': ['c', 'c', 'd', 'd']})

df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict()).to_dict()

>>>
'''
{'col1': {'a': 3, 'b': 1}, 
 'col2': {'c': 2, 'd': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 'col2': ['c', 'c', 'd', 'd']})
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.stack())
```

даст результат

```
col1  a    3.0
      b    1.0
col2  c    2.0
      d    2.0
dtype: float64
```

---

и, на всякий случай, узнать сколько значений d во второй колонке

```
print(df1['col2', 'd'])  # 2
```